# Making CVs / Resume gender neutral

Tags: nlp, human-resources

I want to do a pilot on checking the hypothesis: Hiring Managers have inherent gender bias when shortlisting / rejecting CVs / Resumes.

Essentially, I require a tool which can take a PDF resume as input, and blur/ whiteout all the data which may indicate the gender of the person  (e.g: name, gender/ sex, email ID, photograph, gendered pronouns etc), and the output is the exact same PDF minus all the gendered data. This can be sent to hiring managers of my organization to check how they operate on gender neutral CVs.

Am sorry my coding knowledge is exceptionally weak but I can tweak codes if guided well.

I will go ahead with getting this done through professional coders, but before that I want to do a small pilot for 30 odd pdfs which I can test my hypothesis with. Any help really appreciated.

Comment: I applaud you for this effort.

Comment: What language will the CVs be in? Making a Japanese CV gender neutral is much easier than making a German CV gender neutral.

Comment: Would a tool for plain text resumes be OK too? Plain text is much easier to parse than PDF.

Comment: Hi, I am looking at English language only. The names would be mostly Indian.

Comment: Indeed plain text is much easier to parse than pdf. In case you have coded/ have come across the said tool for plain text, please share the same with me. I can try batch converting all pdfs to plain text files and run your tool to see whether this works.